# Не удается создать экземпляр статического класса

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

Пытаюсь починить проект,но эта ошибка ни как не поддается. Первая это не удается объявить переменную статического поля "PropertyChangedEventArgs" и вторая не удается создать экземпляр статического класса "PropertyChangedEventArgs" и так на всех строках.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static class PropertyChangedEventArgs
{

internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs Ask = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Ask");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs Bid = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Bid");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs BuyOrder = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("BuyOrder");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs CurrentPosition = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentPosition");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs EndPrice = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("EndPrice");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs First = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("First");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs LastMult = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastMult");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs LastPosition = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastPosition");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs LastPrice = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastPrice");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs MiddlePrice = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MiddlePrice");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs SellOrder = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SellOrder");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs StartPrice = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StartPrice");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs Step = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Step");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs TakeProfit = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TakeProfit");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs Temp = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Temp");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs TempMod = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TempMod");


internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs TextPosition = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TextPosition");
```

}

Comment: убери `static` тут `internal static class PropertyChangedEventArgs`

Comment: ну так на то он и статический, чтобы экземпляр не создавался